# An formula derivation question about SMO algorithm of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have a question about how to derive the bottom formula under "Fixing the other ai's .."?

[image]

Here's the completed PDF file [Sequential Minimal Optimization for SVM](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~honavar/smo-svm.pdf)

The screenshot is page 9 of this file.

Answer (score 0):

Question solved.

The constant in the last formula is just representing a constant which is not equivalent to the constant of $y_1a_1 + y_2a_2 = constant$.